# VSC Python complier not printing the whole list

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code for any coding and recently I noticed a strange thing. Whenever I try to print a really long list, the list is not printed completely, it is cut off.

```py
primes=[]
for i in range(1000000):
    primes.append(str(i))
print(primes)
print(len(primes))
print(primes[-1])
```

The list is 1 000 000 units long and last number in the list is 999 999 as expected but the list is not printed completely.
Output is:

```
["0", "1", ..., "1345"
1000000
999999
```

May this be a compiler error?
Thanks for every suggestion.

Comment: It wouldn't be a compiler error. It looks like it's the console limiting how long lines can be. What does `print("\n".join(primes))` print?

Comment: It gets little bit higher but still only up to 2752

Comment: It seems like the console is limiting how much of the output will be shown, which is dumb. You might be able to play around with the console's settings to fix that; although I don't know because I've never used Code for an extended period of time before.

Comment: If run from a bash shell command line it prints them all. Seems to be a limitation of the used terminal.

Comment: It can work well in cmd or PowerShell, but will be truncated within 'integratedTerminal' or 'externalTerminal' in VSCode. So, It seems like the VSCode limitation caused it, and it can't be configured.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in vscode, you need to increase the `Integrated:Scrollback` setting for `terminal` in your vscode settings:

1. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
2. Search for 'terminal scrollback'

[image]

3. Change the value to `100000`
4. Reload the vscode window

Comment: Did not help.
Still only gets to 2752 when printing it as "\n".join() and to 1345 when printing it as a list

Comment: Either external (windows console) or the VSC integrated

Comment: If you are in windows and using git bash try changing the console used by VSCode to git bash instead of using the windows cmd.

Comment: If you want to use windows cmd then: open a cmd window, right-click the title-bar and select Properties. Go to the Layout tab and under Screen Buffer Size set the Height attribute to the desired value of lines, max allowed is 9999.