# VS code doesn't print full string inside terminal Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a string that is 85k characters long. When I print it with python script VS code terminal displays only 21k characters of that string.

Is this normal? How can I set up the VS code to display the whole string?

Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62390257/4901118

Comment: try below after python import statements pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None) # show all text from Text column

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run your script(which prints that large string) in your system terminal.

The internal terminal of VS Code is not as powerful as systems default terminal.