# Show all DataFrame with df.to_string()

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I used PyCharm for a long time. To print all DataFrame I typed:

```
print (df.to_string())
```

Now I want to do the same in VisualStudio Code, but it prints only 117 first values.
[image]

how to deal with it?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/62390257/9938317 helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you run it in debug mode?

This problem is not caused by the terminal line limit, it should be caused by the debug mode configuration. You can run the python file through python command directly in the terminal to get the full output.